# Screen Flow: File Upload Component: Salesforce Mobile

Tags: mobile, screen-flow, fileupload, flow-screen-component, salesforce-mobile-app

I have a screen flow that is using a file upload component, that is working from the browser. When I try to test through the standard mobile app, I am not able to upload files to a related object. I've debugged the mobile output values, and they're null when using the mobile app. Currently using Sales Cloud only.